# Webpack does not create output file (not using webpack-dev-server)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack (NOT the dev-server, I know that doesn't output a file), and it is not creating a dist folder or output file.

I've tried running it directly through `webpack` (installed globally) and `npm run build` which uses a locally installed webpack. Neither work.

Here's my config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/entry.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join('/dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['ng-annotate'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'latest'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    root: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules'),
    ],
    alias: {
      vendor: path.join('/node_modules'),
    },
    fallback: ['node_modules'],
  },
};
```

I've attempted to fix the problem by creating the dist folder manually, but that doesn't work either, the file still is not created.

The weird thing is that it DID build the file before, but now it's stopped. I've not changed the output location or the entry file at any point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any log output from webpack?

Comment: It says that it's outputting the file. 

`λ webpack
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.0.3 and C:\Users\Justin\blog\tsconfig.json
Hash: 2ca3229c0c8fda5a1d6f
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 6260ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  3.98 MB       0  [emitted]  app
    + 353 hidden modules
`

Comment: you're log output implies that it has been generated successfully

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your webpack output path is absolute:

```
output: {
    path: path.join('/dist'), <----
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
},
```

My guess is it's being generated in your root directory. `/dist` would mean from the root of your file system, not relative to your project directory.

It should be:

```
output: {
    path: path.join('./dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
},
```